# How to install pod for all build configurations except certain ones?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dependency-management

I have several build configurations: **Develop, RC, Release, ReleaseDebug**, etc.
I want to install some pod for all configs except **Release** and **ReleaseDebug** ones. I found that we have **:configurations** feature in order to define for which configurations pod should be installed, but what about negation?

Have someone any ideas about this?

P.s. **Please, don't offer solutions where I should define all configs in which pod should appear**. I want a solution where I can define configs in which it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Podfile config with **targets**

```
def develop
  pod 'xxxx'
  pod 'yyyy'
end

def release
  pod 'xxxx'
  pod 'yyyy'
end

target 'Develop' do
  develop
end

target 'Release' do
 release
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to produce extra targets.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify just the items you want in your Podfile like this:

```
pod 'MyPod', :configurations => ['Develop', 'RC']
```

Read about [it here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod).

Comment: it is not mine solution. I don't want change :configurations every time when a new one appears or old one disappears.